# Rotate a block element

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to rotate a block-level box, generated by block element relative to this geometrical center. E.g. as follow:

[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CSS `transform`:

```
transform: rotate(-200deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-200deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-200deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MZcBd/)**

> The transform property is supported in Internet Explorer 10, Firefox, and Opera. You do not need to use CSS prefixes for these.

Answer (score 0):

The property `transform` in CSS3 does this. You need to use vendor prefixes for some browsers. 
Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/gfEL5/

```
-moz-transform: rotate(30deg); /* FF after 3 and before 16 */
-ms-transform: rotate(30deg); /* IE 9 */
-o-transform: rotate(30deg); /* Opera after 10.5 and before 12 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(30deg); /* current Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
transform: rotate(30deg); /* IE after 10, FF after 16 */
```

It rotates around the center by default, but you can set another `transform-origin` as well. More about this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Answer (score 0):

```
 -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
 transform: rotate(30deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
```